# asp.net membership users with passwords and those without

Tags: asp.net, passwords, membership

I am trying to find a way to handle two types of users for an intranet system. There are users who login and there are those who do not. I need to store both types of users in the membership db. Does anyone have a common solution to this problem?

This is for an event booking system. The users who are in AD will see the app. We need to store the O/S Name along with a few other attributes from AD in our membership db. The O/S Name gets captured using the Request.ServerVariables(). We need to store those "requester" details along with other details about the event that is being booked.. In addition to those users, there are users that actually log into the system. I was hoping to store both types of users in the membership db, so that when an event is retrieved, the user details will get retrieved from the membership db as wel

Comment: If the user doesn't log in to the site, how are you supposed to associate a username with them?

Comment: it seems like you would just want to allow anonymous access to the site and only show certain parts/actions for authenticated users, no?  since you can't really login w/o a username/pwd.

Comment: Wouldn't "those who do not" be considered anonymous users?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use 'Integrated Windows Authentication' you have access to some information about the user connecting to your system.

Therefore you could use this information for the general case, without the login.
If a user then want's more access, he can logon to the site with a special username/pwd.

Answer (score 0):

A membership DB would typically restrict access to a set of users for a particular application on an Intranet site. Only those who are in Active Directory as network users would even see the Intranet in the first place. And only a subset of those network users who have been granted privileges for your application in its membership system would see the link and/or be able to gain access in one role or another. Can you be a little more specific with respect to what you are trying to achieve? :-)